# need help in Vb6 save textbox as .csv, but all A column want delimited space

Tags: vba, vb6

need help, in Vb6 save textbox as .csv, but all A column want delimited space

hai, i have problem when save textbox as .csv with vb6 code, i cant find any code to automatically save as delimited space, so all word become column separately

here, my code in VB6 like this

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim mytxt As String
mytxt = Text1.Text
Open "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\history.csv" For Append As #1
Print #1, mytxt
Close #1
End Sub
```

here, my save in history.csv, output like this

```
(10/13/17 04:48PM  E344   T10203 25596595                 00:01'33)
```

[image]

this all text in A column,

i want automatically save history.csv output in Vb6, like this

```
10/13/17(in A Column)
04:48PM(in B Column)
E344(in C Column)
T10105(in D Column)
25596595(in E Column)
00:01'33(in F Column)
```

[image]
    delimited space, until unlimited row
please help me, this Vb6 code problem

Comment: what will happen if a cell has a space in its text?

Comment: Your file is specifically *not* csv. If you want a csv, save the data with separators to begin with, as opposed to fixed-width columns. If you want to keep fixed width columns and still open the file in Excel, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel.

Comment: jsotola, the result will be (10/13/17 04:48PM  E344   T10203 25596595                 00:01'33) in column A, like first picture

Answer (score 1):

I assume your csv file has a comma as separation between the columns?
So a line in the file actually looks like:

```
10/13/17,04:48PM,E344,T10203,25596595,00:01'33
```

If the file looks like that, then it is a csv (comma separated values) file.

If you open the csv file directly from Windows and chose Excel as the program to open it with, then Excel won't process it as an csv file but just as a plain text file.

To open a csv file in Excel you first need to start Excel, then then open the csv file from within Excel. It will then ask you how to handle the file:

[image: Excel csv import (1)]

[image: Excel csv import (2)]

The language in the screenshots is dutch, but I guess the layout will be similar in your local version.

The name of my test file was `tmp.txt`

Comment: Hrqls, i need vb6 code for automatically save just like you explain above

Comment: the code you showed in your post should work ... what does it show when you open the file in notepad?

Answer (score 0):

this may work

found here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

Change the separator in all .csv text files

In Microsoft Windows, click the **Start button**, and then click **Control Panel**.

Open the dialog box for changing **Regional and Language settings**.

Type a new separator in the **List separator box**.

Click OK twice.